# Excel formula for summing all values situated right under each match of a string in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, formula

Here is my data:

[image]

I'm looking for an Excel formula that would calculate the sum of all values in a column, values situated right under every match of a string in that column.
So formula in B1 should return 17 (1+6+10).
It would be great to also pass to the formula the desired row offset of summed values, if possible (this would be 1 in my example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faster, but without explicit offset:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A17,"A",A2:A18)
```

[Slower](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61573769/11683), but with explicit offset:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A17,"A",OFFSET(A1:A17,1,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

`=SUM(INDEX($B$1:$B$17,IF($A$1:$A$17="A",ROW($B$1:$B$17)+1)))`

Or if you list the letters in column D:
`=SUM(INDEX($B$1:$B$17,IF($A$1:$A$17=D1,ROW($B$1:$B$17)+1)))`
[image]